# print cpu usage for an hour and get the average of cpu and print the highest spike in that one hour

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Importing socket library 
import socket
import psutil
import time
import sys


# Function to display hostname and
# IP address 
def get_cpu():
    try:
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        current_cpu = psutil.cpu_percent()

        starttime = time.time()
        while True:
            print("get_cpu:", current_cpu, "host:", host_name, "IP: ", host_ip)
            time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
    except:

        print("Unable to get Hostname and IP and Current CPU")

    # Driver code


get_cpu()  # Function call

# gives a single float value
# psutil.cpu_percent()
# gives an object with many fields
# psutil.virtual_memory()`
# you can convert that object to a dictionary
# dict(psutil.virtual_memo
```

My Current Script just print CPU usage every 60 Seconds,

Expected Output : Get Average of cpu usage for an hour and print the higest spike in that hour.

Thanks

Comment: Store the values of `current_cpu` in a list and break the loop when you reach 60 values. After that, write code to analyze the values and get your output

Comment: Or your could update your current average and the max for every new value, no need for a list. You could then get a lot of values without impacting memory, space complexity O(1) vs O(n) if you use a list. But there could be a numerical loss of precision, I don't know.

Comment: See [Cumulative moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) on Wikipedia.